# Help translating "やりかけの人生"

Tags: translation

Hello Japanese StackExchange. I am humbly asking your help to translate a couple of song titles:

やりかけの人生 (Yari kake no jinsei)

and

夏の初めのイメージ (Natsu no hajime no imēji)

The artist is "Kimiko Kasai" and the album name is "Tokyo Special", if that is of any help.

Comment: What do you think they should be translated like?

Comment: I don't know any Japanese, sadly.

Comment: on this sight we usually don't do any translation; if we did, can you imagine the sorts of traffic this site would be cluttered with?

Comment: I'm sorry that I bothered this community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

やりかけの人生 means "An Unfinished Life".
夏の初めのイメージ means "An Image of An Early Summer".